# PHP error code: Notice: Trying to get property ... of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\index3.php on line 95

Tags: php

I tried to work on the following script;

```
<?php


if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $fullname = $row["fullname"];
        $biography = $row["biography"];
        $email = $row["email"];
        $facebook = $row["facebook"];   
        $twitter = $row["twitter"];
        $gplus = $row["gplus"];
        $linkedin = $row["linkedin"];
      
   
 
echo    '<div id="tabs-'.$row['id'].'" aria-labelledby="ui-id-'.$row['id'].'" role="tabpanel" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-corner-bottom ui-widget-content" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><p>'.$row['biography'].'</p>


<div class="icon-bar">

<p>';



if ($view->$linkedin=='') {
    # code...
    $view = '';
}else{
    $view = '<a href="'.$row[linkedin].'" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>';

}



echo
'
</p>
</div>
</div>';


    }
}

?>
```

but got the following error:

Notice: Trying to get property 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/data-analyst-project-management-cloud-expert-bigdata/' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\index3.php on line 95...

Can someone please help me out.

Comment: `if ($view->$linkedin=='')` What are you checking here? I don't see anywhere you define the object `$view`.

Comment: A wild guess that you just what to check `$linkedin` is empty so the code you want is `if ($linkedin == '')`

Comment: i had earlier tried to define that using $view = (isset($_GET['q']) && $_GET['q'] != '') ? $_GET['q'] : '';

Comment: @catcon you are absolutely spot on. However, I got another error: Warning: Use of undefined constant linkedin - assumed 'linkedin' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\index3.php on line 99. This was when I tried using if ($linkedin == '')

Comment: `$row[linkedin]` -> should be `$row['linkedin']`

Comment: @catcon yes it worked but i now have my result as completely blank without error. I expected to see a result returned with <a href="'https://linkedin...." class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a> from my database cause one of the rows is not blank

Comment: I think you didn't echo the `$view`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any `view` object that you have defined.
If you have defined `view` object then also you code must be

```
if($view->linkedin == ''){
    //code
}
```

Or if you have not defined `view` object the code code may be

```
if($linkedin == ''){
    //code
}
```

Comment: I have been able to resolve the issue using if ($linkedin=='') {
    # code...
    $view = '';
}else{
    echo '<a href="'.$row['linkedin'].'" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>';

}

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to resolve the issue using

```
if ($linkedin=='') {
    # code...
    $view = '';
}else{
    echo '<a href="'.$row['linkedin'].'" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>';

}
```

Thanks to @catcon,@Suresh Chand